# How to Test Facebook Connect Locally with Monaca

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, monaca, onsen-ui2

I am currently working into a project with AngularJS and OnsenUi in Monaca Localkit and i need your help with the integration of facebook login to the application.

I followed the instructions 
[here](https://docs.monaca.io/en/sampleapp/samples/facebook/) but i didn't make it to work.

On Site URL field i use the http://localhost/

Although, i achieved the desired result with plain javascript and serving my index.html from http://localhost:8080. (of course i changed the Site URL to http://localhost:8080)